# Filter out return values with empty field in GraphQL subscriptions

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, graphql, netflix-dgs

I am implementing a subscription API using Netflix's Dgs Framework.

Assuming my schema and other data are as follows:

```
type Subscription {
  mySubscription: MySubscription
}

type MySubscription {
  id: ID
  person(name: String): Person
  eventTime: String
}

type Person {
  name: String
  age: Int
}
```

The above is just a simple example to facilitate describing the issue I'm facing. The actual scenario is even more complex than this example.

The issue I'm facing is that in the resolver of the subscription, when I consume data from the message queue, I generate a `MySubscription` and push it to the subscribers.

```
@DgsSubscription
public Flux<MySubscription> mySubscription() {
  // The data from the message queue is transformed into a map.
  Map<String, String> jsonDataMap = gson.fromJson(data, Map.class);

  // The Person field will be generated in the resolver of the Person.
  return MySubscription.newBuilder()
            .id(jsonDataMap.get("id"))
            .eventTime(jsonDataMap.get("eventTime"))
            .build();
}
```

In the resolver of `Person`, there is a parameter called `name` that allows the client to specify the desired name to obtain the corresponding data. When the name in the data does not match the name specified by the client, it will return null.

So, when I receive three pieces of data from the message queue, but only one of them matches the `name` specified by the client, three `MySubscription` objects will be generated, but only one will have the `Person` data.

I know that I can place the name parameter on the interface of the subscription, like this:

```
type Subscription {
  mySubscription(name: String): MySubscription
}
```

With this approach, it can filter out data that does not match the specified `name` when receiving it, thereby avoiding the creation of unnecessary `MySubscription` objects. But I believe that scattering the same parameter across different places can confuse the client. So I would like to maintain the schema as shown at the top.

I would like to know if there is any way to avoid generating a `MySubscription` with an empty `person` in this situation.